# Logitech k860 keyboard: keys not working

Tags: keyboard, logitech-keyboard

I've bought this keyboard in January. After a few months, it started doing strange things: every so often some keys would have random effects, like the spacebar switching tabs on my computer, which was strange, because I removed the spacebar and there was no dirt underneath; also, as I searched I found no shortcut that uses the spacebar on Windows to switch tabs. After putting the keyboard aside for a while and returning to it, it worked as normal. This has happened 2 or 3 times already.

Now, I have a problem that many keys on the right side of the keyboard are simply not working, like the "p" key, the shift key and many numbers on the numpad.

This problem is not only on Windows, as I had also booted my PC on Fedora and it had the same problem.

I did a few things already:

- Uninstalled Logitech Options Software and all the drives of the keyboard;
- Checked for keyboard updates;
- Used a shortcut on the keyboard to reset it;
- Activated the filter setting on the control panel of Windows (saw this on a different question here);
- Changed the batteries;
- Changed the USB port that the unifying receiver is plugged.

Comment: If it does the same on multiple OSes, it's not a software issue.